# What do I need to know to build an HTTP server in C?

Tags: c, http, webserver, requirements

Some say that in order to build an HTTP server I should follow the [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) standards. Which is ok, but as a completely new C developer I would like to know what modules, techniques I will need to make implement the HTTP protocol to handles html, css, js and images.

I'm not trying to reinvent the well I just need a starting point to learn C. And my experience is that building something useful in a project manner is the best way to learn something new.

P.S. I would like to build it from scratch if it's possible.

Comment: A long, long, time ago some other people wanted the same thing, [and I thank them for it](http://www.apache.org).

Comment: And not so long ago some other people made something even better http://nginx.org/ :)

Comment: As a straightforward implementation, which also could be incorporated into your own app this might do: http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Answer (score 6):

An HTTP server is a simple text-based server; all protocol messages are sent in plain-text. Furthermore, it is stateless (i.e. no need to remember anything about previous connections - handle each request as if it was a new one). With these concepts in mind, you basically need to understand how `socket programming` works (and how to program well in C). Socket programming also depends on the library you are using (generally, `POSIX` is used for non-Windows systems, otherwise `WinSock2` is used for Windows).

The other features (HTML, js, etc.) are handled by the browser. The server simply sends the data to the client (generally via TCP unless you are recreating the transport protocol as well).

Also, arguably the best reference for socket programming (in C and C++) is [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

**EDIT**

On a very primitive level, the pseduocode for an HTTP server looks like this:

```
while(1) {
  client = accept(); // Receive some connection
  recv(client, req); // Receive the request from the client
  // ... Do some HTTP request processing ...
  send(client, resp); // Send the client the response/data
}
```

That said, I just re-read your post and, perhaps, socket programming is not the best point to learn C. Not that it cannot be done (I think this is where I started as well, although now I see much easier routes), it's just much more difficult to wrap your head around both the language and the networking layer. There are many other things to create to get used to the idea of pointers, memory management, structs, etc. You can try creating simple file readers/writers creating some sort of inventory/calculation script. I just suggest these since socket API's look very foreign for first time users who are comfortable with C already.

Answer (score 2):

html, js, css and images are handled by the browser. The server just has to deliver the content. As long as this has not it's own dynamic it could be handled. The remaining story has not much to do with the C-language.